# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawerlayout

Buena tarde!! estoy obteniendo el siguiente error, ya busque por otros foros y no puedo solucionarlo, ojala alguien me pueda ayudar.

Error:

```
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
                                                 at mx.com.omnius.taximxtraking.base.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:52)
                                                 at mx.com.omnius.taximxtraking.TrakingActivity.onCreate(TrakingActivity.java:72)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Estas son las lineas en donde me arroja el error

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Este es mi código completo.

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {


    protected FrameLayout frameLayout;
    protected ListView mDrawerList;
    protected String[] listArray = { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", "Item 5" };
    protected static int position;
    private static boolean isLaunch = true;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout);

        frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, listArray));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                openActivity(position);
            }
        });

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                       /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,              /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.menu,     /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.open_drawer,       /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.close_drawer)      /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */ 
        { 
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(listArray[position]);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
                super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        if(isLaunch){
            isLaunch = false;
            openActivity(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param position
     * 
     * Launching activity when any list item is clicked. 
     */
    protected void openActivity(int position) {

        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        BaseActivity.position = position; //Setting currently selected position in this field so that it will be available in our child activities. 

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item1Activity.class));
            break;
        case 1:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item2Activity.class));
            break;
        case 2:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item3Activity.class));
            break;
        case 3:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item4Activity.class));
            break;
        case 4:
            //startActivity(new Intent(this, Item5Activity.class));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Item Position::"+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* We can override onBackPressed method to toggle navigation drawer*/
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)){
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }else {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
        }
    }
}
```

Ojala me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)

Answer (score 1):

Como muestra el `logcat` estas recibiendo ***null*** para activar el "botón atrás" en la `toolbar`. Dentro de tu Oncreate debes inicializarlo para luego poder utilizarlo. Quedaria asi:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Esto iria ublicado despues de: `setContentView(R.layout.navigation_drawer_base_layout)`